# Align images vertically (flush top), not flush bottom

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a `div` tag, that contains images. The default seems to align images flush bottom, assuming different vertically sized images. How do I change the code, such that I get the images to align flush top?

Here is the complete HTML code.

CSS

```
    #page {
        position: relative;
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        float: left;
        border: none;
    }
    .divPortfolioImageRowFirst
    {
        display: table-row;
    }
    .divPortfolioImageCol1 {
        vertical-align: top;
    }
```

HTML

```
    <div id="page">
        <div>
            <div id="divProductLogos">
                <div class='divPortfolioImageRowFirst'>
                    <div class='divPortfolioImageCol1' style='line-height: 78px' id="divProductLogos_1">
                        <img style='margin-left: 0px;' src="./images/portfolio/ProductLogos_1.png"/>
                        <img style='margin-left: 15px;' src="./images/portfolio/ProductLogos_2.png"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The addition of "vertical-align: top;" and "line-height: 78px;" did not do the trick.

What did I forget / not do?

Comment: You don't need display block on divPortfolioImageCol1, divs are naturally display block, unless it is changed somewhere

Comment: What I mean by flush top is that the images should vertically align at the top, leaving a ragged bottom. Right now, the images align flush bottom, leaving a clean bottom and a ragged top. I want the inverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like the following:

The **HTML**:

```
<div id="divProductLogos">
    <div class='divPortfolioImageRowFirst'>
        <div class='divPortfolioImageCol1'>
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/200" />
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/250" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the **CSS**:

```css
.divPortfolioImageRowFirst {
    border: 2px dotted gray;
    padding: 10px;
}
.divPortfolioImageCol1 {
    border: 1px dotted gray;
}
.divPortfolioImageCol1 img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Originally, you had too many floats affecting the layout, and that was causing some problems.

You could also use CSS table cells depending on other design considerations.

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/9fhCS/

**About the Vertical-align Property**

The `vertical-align` property is not inherited, so it as to be applied to the inline elements that need to be adjusted.  Specifying `vertical-align` on the parent container will not affect the child elements.

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align

Comment: I tested the solution on the real page and the code worked. The answer seems to be the required ".divPortfolioImageCol1 img { vertical-align: top; }". Simply placing "vertical-align: top" inside the .divPortfolioImageCol1{} did not do the trick. Interesting. I thought styles trickled down. I guess they do not.

Comment: Hi Sarah, that is a good point to note.  Please see my comment regarding the vertical-align property.

Comment: Hi Marc, I read your comment and that fact is not obvious at all. When I learnt CSS, I was taught that styles tricked down from the parent container. I will have to keep a mental note, or write it down, that which styles, vertical-align, for one, break the rule. Thanks.

Comment: Not all CSS properties are inherited.  In some cases, it makes sense to inherit a property (font size for example) and in other cases, not.  When in doubt, you need to read the original W3.org spec.  When it comes to CSS, you need to keep you wits about you! All the best. :)

Answer (score 1):

First, `valign` isn't a valid property, you should use `vertical-align: top;`

You will also need to set `line-height` to the height of the tallest image.

Comment: I implemented the addition, as you can see, and that did not do the trick. You can test on your own using a local browser, simply by using two different vertically sized images. One of mine is 78px and the other is 38px. If everything works, as desired, the images align at the top with a ragged bottom.